# Rails validate format. "001" should be valid but not "1" or 1. /\A\d\d\d\z/ not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, rspec, shoulda

I have been running into an issue when trying to test the following validation in one of my models:

```
validate :clientnumber, format: { with: /\A\d\d\d\z/ }
```

Essentially I want to allow "001" to be a valid entry, but not allow "1". When I run these tests:

```
it do
   should allow_value('880', '546', '001', '999').for(:clientnumber)
end
it do
   should_not allow_value('foo', '8ar', '1' ).for(:clientnumber)
end
```

I get the following as results.

```
should allow clientnumber to be set to any of ["880", "546", "001", "999"]
```

which passes but,

```
should not allow clientnumber to be set to any of ["foo", "8ar", "1"] (FAILED - 1)
```

fails

Initially I had even tried testing plain integers in there too but realized it was moot when even the string form was getting through. When testing the regex on rubular it doesn't return any matches against single or 2 digit numbers. Ultimately I would like it to only allow strings (which is the datatype on the table) that are of the form /\d\d\d/. What am I missing that causes both "001" and "1" to get through?

Also I noticed that when testing an integer, the test will fail on the integer even if it is to the right of the invalid string-number.

Comment: I'm not sure why the regex isn't working, but what if you added `length: { minimum : 3 }`?

Comment: Also, maybe `/\A\d{3}\z/` would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you using invalid validation helper i.e. [validate](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validate) instead of [validates](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates).